# Fail to restore CSS file in PhpStorm

Tags: windows, phpstorm, restore

While I was working in PhpStorm on a website computer restarted and an error appears. I using Windows 10. After restart CSS file was empty and I lost my work. The CSS file appears like it still have 9kb, but in PhpStorm it is empty.

I've tried to restore from PhpStorm, but the Local History is empty too.

[image: Error]

Can I restore it? If I can, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you save the file prior to the crash? If not, take a look at [PHPstorm's autosave functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/saving-and-reverting-changes.html).

Also, and I don't mean to be condescending here: frequently saving your stuff and proper backups are important.